# Core Data: how to avoid saving to persistent store until all data has been processed?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new to Core Data and am struggling with a problem. In my game I occasionally have to work on and then save a large amount of data before moving on to the next level (all on the main thread). The flow is something like this:

```
workOutResults()  
processUpdates()
saveContext  
moveToNextLevel()
```

Because *processUpdates()* needs to fetch data that was updated in *workOutResults()*, I have to saveContext after *workOutResults()* otherwise I get an ‘unrecognized selector’ error.

So the flow is now:

```
workOutResults()
saveContext 
processUpdates() 
saveContext 
moveToNextLevel()
```

This works well, but it takes about 5 seconds (which I am fine with). My issue is what happens if the app is killed while in the middle of this process (battery fail for example, or the user may exit the app for some reason)? Say this happens:

```
workOutResults()
saveContext
[app is killed here]
```

When the app relaunches, it will attempt to run *workOutResults()* again and I will get duplicate data because it has saved it.

So my question is how can I ONLY save the data to the persistent store at the end of the process? How do I avoid having to save between *workOutResults()* and *processUpdates()* in order to work on the same data?

Comment: I don't get why you need the first save. Unrecognized selector errors are not a typical result of not having saved to a persistent store.

Comment: It may be that having to do the first save is the problem, in which case I will post another question about that. So should I be able to fetch data in workOutResults(), update it without saving, and still be able to fetch it again in processUpdates()? I will be fetching 'stale' data surely, hence why I have to save in between?

Comment: how are you fetching the data? if you are not forcing it to refresh, I would also expect that the context would return you the modified data, that are dirty

Comment: By default a fetch request on a managed object context includes unsaved changes on that context. You can disable that, but you'd know if you had.

Comment: As others have said, `Unrecognized selector` has nothing to do with save context, add an exception breakpoint and print the error to see what exactly is the problem

Comment: Regarding maintaining a consistent state, I prefer to create a child context and work on the child context and save the child context and parent context at the end of a transaction (group of tasks). That way if the app is killed in between the child context isn't saved and the data would be in a consistent state

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It would seem that my problem lies in getting an 'unrecognized selector' error in between my two function calls. I have posted a separate question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310482/unrecognized-selector-crash-in-core-data-unless-i-call-savecontext-first

Comment: Regarding creating a child context, I like that idea. But I thought having multiple contexts on the same thread was frowned upon?