# Unrecognized selector crash in Core Data unless I call saveContext first

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here are three functions from my code:

```
func workOutResults() {
  var fixtures = [Fixture]()

  let fixtureFetch: NSFetchRequest<Fixture> = Fixture.fetchRequest()

  do {
    fixtures = try coreDataStack.managedContext.fetch(fixtureFetch)
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }

  for fixture in fixtures {
    // do stuff here
  }
}

func processUpdates() {
  // relevant code snippet below
  let theTable = loadLeagueTableFor(leagueName: "Championship", cds: cds)
}

func loadLeagueTableFor(leagueName: String, cds: CoreDataStack) -> [Club] {
  var leagueArray = [Club]()

  // Set up the sort descriptors 
  let pointsSortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = {
  let compareSelector = #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:))
  return NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Club.leaguePoints),
                          ascending: false,
                          selector: compareSelector)
  }()

  let goalDiffSortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = {
  let compareSelector = #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:))
  return NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Club.leagueGoalDiff),
                          ascending: false,
                          selector: compareSelector)
  }()

  let goalsForSortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = {
  let compareSelector = #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:))
  return NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Club.leagueGoalsFor),
                          ascending: false,
                          selector: compareSelector)
  }()

  let clubNameSortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = {
  let compareSelector = #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:))
  return NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Club.name),
                          ascending: true,
                          selector: compareSelector)
  }()

  // Do the Fetch request of Clubs, placing them in order into leagueArray
  let clubFetch: NSFetchRequest<Club> = Club.fetchRequest()
  clubFetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Club.league.nameID), leagueName)
  clubFetch.sortDescriptors = [pointsSortDescriptor, goalDiffSortDescriptor, goalsForSortDescriptor, clubNameSortDescriptor]

  do {
    leagueArray = try cds.managedContext.fetch(clubFetch)
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
  }

  cds.saveContext()

  return leagueArray
}
```

If I call...

```
workOutResults()
coreDataStack.saveContext()
processUpdates()
```

... everything works fine. Yet if I call...

```
workOutResults()
processUpdates()
```

... I get the following error in loadLeagueTableFor():

```
2018-01-17 19:37:38.228954+0000 Tycoon[1331:32725] -[__NSCFNumber localizedStandardCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000022
2018-01-17 19:37:38.278901+0000 Tycoon[1331:32725] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber localizedStandardCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000022'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104da212b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103d6ef41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e23024 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d24f78 ___forwarding___ + 1432
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d24958 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Foundation                          0x00000001037aaad2 _NSCompareObject + 46
6   Foundation                          0x0000000103806097 _NSSortFunctionMany + 674
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d1b3bc __CFSimpleMergeSort + 124
8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d1b41c __CFSimpleMergeSort + 220
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d1b41c __CFSimpleMergeSort + 220
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d1b41c __CFSimpleMergeSort + 220
11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d1b2fb CFSortIndexes + 827
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104d51726 CFMergeSortArray + 454
13  Foundation                          0x00000001037aa81e _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 596
14  Foundation                          0x00000001037aa570 -[NSArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:] + 531
15  CoreData                            0x000000010477909e -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 4590
16  libswiftCoreData.dylib              0x00000001045e8f1a )
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

So saving the context in between the two fetches avoids the crash, but poses a problem as it means I have to save in a place I would rather not. Any idea why I am getting the error?

Comment: Is your `leaguePoints` attribute a number or string? Looks like you're trying to use a string comparison method in a number field. When you call save it's probably doing some before save validation and/or setting a default value of nil hence the comparison works.

Comment: @Rog `leaguePoints`, `leagueGoalDiff` and `leagueGoalsFor` are `Int32`. name is a `string`. How should I write the Int32 comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why this would *ever* work, because you're comparing numeric values with `compareSelector`, which you define to be a method on `NSString`. The error message describes this exactly-- you're trying to compare two numbers using a method that doesn't exist for numbers.

When using sort descriptors, the `selector` and `comparator` versions of the constructors are only necessary if you don't want the common sorting implied by the value of `ascending`. In the case of numeric values, if you simply want them sorted by value, you don't need either. You can simply use something like

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Club.leaguePoints),
                      ascending: false)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, changing the descriptors to your suggestion fixed it. For example: `let pointsSortDescriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Club.leaguePoints), ascending: false)`